# Wireless Indicator/LED Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

I have an HP Envy M6 Sleekbook/Laptop. It originally came with Window$ 8.1, x64 and is now dual boot with Linux Mint.
It has an integrated Ralink Wireless 802.11bgn + Bluetooth 3.0 Combo RT3290 Adapter. The f12 key contains the wireless indicator light.

When using Window$, and it is on, the LED is a light blue/white.
[image: f12 LED on indicator]

When it is off/airplane mode, the LED is amber/light orange.
[image: f12 LED off indicator]

When using Mint, the light is always amber regardless of on/off.
The amber light is annoying and I would like it to work right. 
Bluetooth doesn't work either (perhaps separate thread?)

Comment: It's a bit late but what's the output of `/sys/class/leds/`?